# indentação no vs code como configurar

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentação

como trocar os espaços em branco por pontos flutuantes na indentação no VS Code[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Opção 1**

Vc pode mudar de `Dot Spaces` para `Tabs`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Opção 2**

Ou então conforme a última atualização `1.43` vc pode ocultar os pontos, e só mostra-los quando fizer a seleção usando a opção `editor.renderWhitespace` veja no link da documentação https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_render-whitespace-on-selection

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: vlw irmaozao. mas na vdd minha intençao era usar os pontos flutuantes mesmo.
mas descobri que essa funcao chegou na na versao que vc mencionou e fui exatamente nessa opcao de renderizar os espaços em branco.
muito obrigado pela atencao

Comment: @LpcNca legal que chegou a uma solução com as dicas. Se vc acha que o problema foi resolvido considere marcar a resposta como aceita nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas da resposta. Assim sua pergunta não fica em aberto mesmo já tendo sido resolvida

Comment: mais uma dica!!! vlw mano TMJ!!!!